# How is the Object class implemented (methods like hashCode and internal fields)?

Tags: java, object, jvm

I am curious how is the Object class implemented. For example

1. a method `hashCode()` or `wait()`
2. How is the internal state represented.
   For instance, an intrinsic lock or the data structure for storing threads that called object's `wait()`.

In order to find these out, I have downloaded a source of OpenJDK and started to dig in. First thing, I came across was \openjdksrc\jdk\src\share\native\java\lang\Object.c file, containing, among others:

```
static JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
    {"hashCode",    "()I",                    (void *)&JVM_IHashCode},
    {"wait",        "(J)V",                   (void *)&JVM_MonitorWait},
    {"notify",      "()V",                    (void *)&JVM_MonitorNotify},
    {"notifyAll",   "()V",                    (void *)&JVM_MonitorNotifyAll},
    {"clone",       "()Ljava/lang/Object;",   (void *)&JVM_Clone},
};
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_java_lang_Object_registerNatives(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls)
{
    (*env)->RegisterNatives(env, cls,
                            methods, sizeof(methods)/sizeof(methods[0]));
}

JNIEXPORT jclass JNICALL
Java_java_lang_Object_getClass(JNIEnv *env, jobject this)
{
    if (this == NULL) {
        JNU_ThrowNullPointerException(env, NULL);
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, this);
    }
}
```

and to my understanding, methods[] array defines a mapping between the native implementations of Object's methods. So for example, Object's `hashCode()` is mapped to `JVM_IHashCode` function. The `JVM_IHashCode` is implemented in \openjdksrc\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp. And here is my first question. **Why this is already a part of VM itself (it is defined already in \openjdksrc\hotspot\src\share\vm)?**
But lets move to the code of `JVM_IHashCode`:

```
JVM_ENTRY(jint, JVM_IHashCode(JNIEnv* env, jobject handle))
  JVMWrapper("JVM_IHashCode");
  // as implemented in the classic virtual machine; return 0 if object is NULL
  return handle == NULL ? 0 : ObjectSynchronizer::FastHashCode (THREAD, JNIHandles::resolve_non_null(handle)) ;
JVM_END
```

**Why if object is null we return here 0?** I guess an NPE should be thrown. Otherwise, the FastHashCode is called from \openjdksrc\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\synchronizer.cpp and eventually at some point of time, the get_next_hash is called that calculates the real value.
**Once it is calculated the question is where it is stored?**

```
    intptr_t ObjectSynchronizer::FastHashCode (Thread * Self, oop obj) {

...CUT...

      ObjectMonitor* monitor = NULL;
      markOop temp, test;
      intptr_t hash;
      markOop mark = ReadStableMark (obj);
    
...CUT...

      if (mark->is_neutral()) {
        hash = mark->hash();              // this is a normal header
        if (hash) {                       // if it has hash, just return it
          return hash;
        }
        hash = get_next_hash(Self, obj);  // allocate a new hash code
        temp = mark->copy_set_hash(hash); // merge the hash code into header
        // use (machine word version) atomic operation to install the hash
        test = (markOop) Atomic::cmpxchg_ptr(temp, obj->mark_addr(), mark);
        if (test == mark) {
          return hash;
        }
        // If atomic operation failed, we must inflate the header
        // into heavy weight monitor. We could add more code here
        // for fast path, but it does not worth the complexity.
      } 
...CUT...
      return hash;
    }
```

So the oop class/struct (**?**) has a markOop class/struct (**?**) where the hash value is stored. Funnily I can't locate these classes/structs. All I was able to find was:

```
class oopDesc {
  friend class VMStructs;
 private:
  volatile markOop  _mark;
...CUT...
```

in \openjdksrc\hotspot\src\share\vm\oops\oop.hpp
which seems to have markOop in a private field. **But then what really is "oop" which is refered in the rest of the code? And where to find markOop definition?** I have found a corresponding:

```
class markOopDesc: public oopDesc 
...CUT...
```

in \openjdksrc\hotspot\src\share\vm\oops\markOop.hpp but it is only full of enums and can't find a field where the hash value can be stored.
If someone could answer at least a part of my **questions** I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: The hashCode of `null` is indeed supposed to be zero: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Why not just use a static counter in the Object class?

Answer (score 2):

Java object's hash code is stored in object header, once it's calculated.

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml

http://hunmr.blogspot.com/2012/08/java-performance-tunning.html

from hotspot/src/share/vm/oops/markOop.hpp

```
// The markOop describes the header of an object.
//
// Note that the mark is not a real oop but just a word.
// It is placed in the oop hierarchy for historical reasons.
//
// Bit-format of an object header (most significant first, big endian layout below):
//
//  32 bits:
//  --------
//             hash:25 ------------>| age:4    biased_lock:1 lock:2 (normal object)
//             JavaThread*:23 epoch:2 age:4    biased_lock:1 lock:2 (biased object)
//             size:32 ------------------------------------------>| (CMS free block)
//             PromotedObject*:29 ---------->| promo_bits:3 ----->| (CMS promoted object)
//
```

Comment: For reference: "OOP" here means "Ordinary Object Pointer".

Comment: Thanks! A few more questions poped up in my head. I read on the website you are refering that the object header takes 8 bytes. Here it looks like it is 16 bytes (4 bytes each line * 4 lines). I am also curious about sizes of some fields. Why hash is only 25 bits? And why lock is 2 bits? I think it would be enough to have just 1 bit for the lock. And what are the fields: age, epoch and promo_bits?

Comment: @Janek, good question. I think the "normal" and "biased" object states are mutual exclusived. and also for "CMD free" and "CMS promoted". Age is used to implement generation based memory management. epoch?promo_bits? I don't know. all the answer is in the sourcecode. :)

Comment: @whunmr What do you mean when you say the hashcode is stored in the "object header file"? The header is a static file in C/C++? Or is a new header file being generated for each Class, where one of the values in it the 32-bit data that you have described above?

Comment: @mk1 for "object header" I mean the head/beginning part of memory occupied by java object instance.